# "Class variable needs to be a factor" error for csv-read datasets

Tags: r, syntax, discretization

I am looking to discretise continuous features in [machine-learning](/questions/tagged/machine-learning) datasets, in particular, using supervised [discretisation](/questions/tagged/discretisation). It turns out that [r](/questions/tagged/r) [has a package/method for this][1](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/arulesCBA/versions/1.1.6/topics/discretizeDF.supervised), great! But since I am not proficient in R I have some issues and I would greatly appreciate if you could help.

I get an error

> class variable needs to be a factor.

I looked at an example online, and they do not seem to have this problem, but I do. Note that I do not quite understand the [syntax](/questions/tagged/syntax) `V2 ~ .`, other than that `V2` should be a column name.

```
library(caret)
library(Rcpp)
library(arulesCBA)

filename <- "wine.data"
dataset <- read.csv(filename, header=FALSE)
dataset2 <- discretizeDF.supervised(V2 ~ ., dataset, method = "mdlp")
```

R reports the following error:

> Error in .parseformula(formula, data) :    class variable needs to be
>   a factor!

You may find the dataset wine.data here: https://pastebin.com/hvDbEtMN
The first parameter of [discretizeDF.supervised](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/arulesCBA/versions/1.1.6/topics/discretizeDF.supervised) is a formula and that seems to be the problem.

Please help! Thank you in advance.

Comment: try data$V2<-as.factor(data$V2)   ; it sets V2 as factor, "V2 ~  . "is your formula stating: V2 is the response to everything on the right side of tilde, (explanatory factors) ,  ". "mostly just means every column

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! That helped. Btw setting the column as a factor rather than integers solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in the vignette, this is meant to implement:

> several supervised methods to convert continuous variables into a
>   categorical variables (factor) suitable for association rule mining
>   and building associative classifiers.

If you look at your V2 column, it's continuous:

```
test = read.csv("wine_dataset.txt",header=FALSE)
str(test)
'data.frame':   178 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ V1 : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ V2 : num  14.2 13.2 13.2 14.4 13.2 ...
 $ V3 : num  1.71 1.78 2.36 1.95 2.59 1.76 1.87 2.15 1.64 1.35 ...
```

What you need is a target that is categorical, so that the algo can find suitable methods to discretize it for finding associations. For example:

```
#this cuts V2 into 4 categories according to where they fall in the range
test$V2 = factor(cut(test$V2,4,labels=1:4))
dataset2 <- discretizeDF.supervised(V2 ~ ., dataset, method = "mdlp")
```

The above is one way to get around, but you need to find ways to cut V2 well. If you need to use the target as a continuous, then you can use `discretizeDF` from arules, and I also see that your first column is 1,2,3 only:

```
test = read.csv("wine_dataset.txt",header=FALSE)
test2 = data.frame(test[,1:2],discretizeDF(test[,-c(1:2)]))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Indeed I needed a categorical target, but I got the same error when I used the appropriate columns. But, as you noted, the main problem was that the target column was not specified as a factor, which should/could have been done by cutting continuous data or using already integer column and converting it to a factor. I fixed that and it worked!

Comment: Oh great. glad you found a way to get it to work :)